# probability that two randomly selected numbers are equal

Tags: probability

I have two sets, say $S_1 = \{1, ..., n\}$ and $S_2 = \{0, 1, ..., n - 3\}$
How do I find the probability that randomly selected numbers $n \in S_1$ and $m \in S_2$ are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your elementary event implies selecting of a number from $S_1$ and another (maybe equal, maybe not) number from $S_2$. There are $n\cdot(n-2)$ such events, and $n-3$ of them lead to the desired outcome (i.e., that the numbers are equal). Hence the probability in question is $n-3\over n(n-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is $n$ elements in $S_1$ so the probability of picking any element would be $\frac{1}{n}$. In $S_2$ there is $n-2$ elements so the probability would be $\frac{1}{n-2}$.

$$P=\frac{1}{n^2-2n}$$